# Get handles as a number in order to apply function and operate mathematicaly

Tags: string, matlab, function, user-interface, handles

The program asks for input in `gui` editbox as a value, then it takes this value and applies the equation to get the pressure. I haven't been able to do so and I heard from some classmates that matlab takes the input as a string and doesn't operate strings.

`get(handles.spl,'String')` this is how I get the value, I tried `get(handles.spl,'Double')` instead but it didn't work, also tried `str2double`.

I don't know what else to try, I'm also pretty new in programming.
I'd appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the `uicontrol` `String` property returns...a string. So you'll need to convert it to a number using `str2double`.

```
u = uicontrol('style', 'edit', 'String', '42');

strvalue = get(u, 'String');
numvalue = str2double(strvalue);
%   42
```